# Are there any good open source iOS application templates out there?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I was wondering if anyone knows of any good open source app templates out there.

I've been noticing that I commonly use a few open source projects in every app that I write, like appirater, flurry, in app settings kit, etc.

Does anyone know of any app templates out there that use any of these already?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I wrote one.

https://github.com/steipete/PSiOSAppTemplate

Whats in the box?

Localization for English/German pre-setup

Xcode agnostic gitignore setup

Completely setup autoupdating via Hockey, with custom Target for instant App-Distribution. All you need is to modify the ssh script in the BetaDistribute target and setup a server with the Hockey server parts: https://github.com/TheRealKerni/Hockey

Integrated Crash Reporter Server sender. Just activate in PSDefines and https://github.com/TheRealKerni/CrashReporterDemo

Adapted symbolicator for remove crash report symbolication

Integrated super fast and efficient YAJL JSON parser http://lloyd.github.com/yajl/

PSFoundation for all those little categories, reachability and co: https://github.com/steipete/PSFoundation

Flurry for app statistics. Just add your statistics key to kFlurryStatisticsKey http://www.flurry.com/

Custom logging (cocoa-lumberjack) with file logging and NSLogger integration See https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack and https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger

Colored Logging-Output using XcodeColors in Simulator http://deepit.ru/products/XcodeColors/info/

RegexKitLite http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/

FTLocationSimualtor for debugging CoreLocation in the Simulator https://github.com/futuretap/FTLocationSimulator

asi-http-request for everything http-related; better alternative to NSURLConnection https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request

Comment: That's funny. I found your template and blog a few weeks ago.  I've been thinking about forking it and adding a few things that I tend to use alot.

Comment: Please, I welcome you to do so. InAppSettingsKit and some other stuff would be a great fit, but as they're pretty easy to add I try to keep it lightweight.

Comment: InAppSettingsKit, Appirater, and Sharekit were the three main things I was considering adding to it.